# xml:all wants all or nothing?

Tags: xml, schema

Looking for an XML Guru to answer an anomly.  I've checked multiple web pages with little luck.

I have a complex data type with an xs:all in it set to minOccurs=0 like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="EffectRecord">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">
                <xs:all minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:element name="P1Name" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="P2Name" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="P3Name" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="BasedOnStat" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:all>
                <xs:attribute name="EffectName" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="Description" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="CostFormula" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

I use the type later in my schema like this:

```
xs:element name="World">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Statistics">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="Statistic" type="StatRecord"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
                <xs:key name="StatKey">
                    <xs:selector xpath="World/Statistics"/>
                    <xs:field xpath="@Name"/>
                </xs:key>
                <xs:keyref refer="StatKey" name="StatRef">
                    <xs:selector xpath="EffectRecord"/>
                    <xs:field xpath="BasedOnStat"/>
                </xs:keyref>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Effects">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:element name="Effect" type="EffectRecord"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When I attempt to write a document using this schema in my schema driven XML editor, it is fine with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<Statistics>
    <Statistic Name="Strength" Abbreviation="STR" Cost="3"/>
    <Statistic Name="Toughness" Abbreviation="TOU" Cost="2"/>
</Statistics>
<Effects>
    <Effect EffectName="foo" Description="A foo" CostFormula="P1*2">

    </Effect>
</Effects>
```

BUT this generates the error **The content of element 'Effect' is not complete. One of '{P2Name, P3Name, BasedOnStat}' is expected.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<Statistics>
    <Statistic Name="Strength" Abbreviation="STR" Cost="3"/>
    <Statistic Name="Toughness" Abbreviation="TOU" Cost="2"/>
</Statistics>
<Effects>
    <Effect EffectName="foo" Description="A foo" CostFormula="P1*2">
        <P1Name></P1Name>
    </Effect>
</Effects>
```

Why does the inclusion of one of these elements mean they all must be  included?  This does not match any of the defitions I cna find of xs:all.  What I want is for all of the sub-elements of the all to be optional but show up at most one time.

Thanks, really beating my head against the screen here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I answered my own question.  I had my minOccurs at the wrong level.  For the effect I want it belongs on each element, not on the all.